Selenium Chrome Driver in Docker Container Not Running
I am new to docker. I need to scrape a website using Selenium chrome driver by Python from a docker container.
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip
# Download ChromeDriver
RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/128.0.6613.84/win32/chrome-win32.zip
RUN unzip chrome-win32.zip -d /usr/local/bin/
# Copy your project files
COPY . /app
USER root
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install selenium==3.141.0
RUN pip install urllib3==1.26.16
RUN pip install webdriver-manager
CMD ["python3", "seleniumdriver.py"]

Python Code:
from selenium import webdriver
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options=chromeOptions
)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()

Docker Build: docker -t seleniumdriver .
Docker Run: docker seleniumdriver
OS: Windows 10
Docker build is success but docker run is throwing an error.
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Tried different approaches but nothing worked me.

1- First you need to download the linux version of the chrome driver you are using since you are using the docker image python:3.11-slim-buster base on linux. You can use this  link to get it: https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/128.0.6613.84/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
2- Once you download it, add the folder that contains 'chromedriver' executables to your PATH.
That's it this should resolve your issue.

@BENHACHMEELHASSANE Since, I am new to docker, I don't where the chrome is getting downloaded. Can u pls share the code on how to move the chrome to desired path and add that path in the python code.

A small change made it work.
Dockerfile
From
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip
# Download ChromeDriver
RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/128.0.6613.84/win32/chrome-win32.zip
RUN unzip chrome-win32.zip -d /usr/local/bin/
...

To
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip chromium-driver


Additionally, to verify that these changes work, I make the browser take a screenshot.
You can use the following steps to verify.
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip chromium-driver
# Copy your project files
COPY . /app
USER root
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install selenium==3.141.0
RUN pip install urllib3==1.26.16
RUN pip install webdriver-manager

VOLUME ["/app"]

CMD ["python3", "seleniumdriver.py"]

seleniumdriver.py
from selenium import webdriver
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=chromeOptions
)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
driver.quit()

Commands
$ docker build -t seleniumdriver .
$ docker run --name seleniumdriver -p 80:80 -v .:/app seleniumdriver 

You could see screenshot.png in the same folder.

Can u pls explain this command: -p 80:80 -v .:/app seleniumdriver.
Why we are binding host machine port 80 to docker container port 80?

-p is for port forwarding, mapping port 80 in the container to port 80 on the local machine. It might not be necessary; it was initially added just to ensure that the browser can access the network. -v is for mount file system.

Can I run above docker image in AWS faregate compute service. Will it work?
If it doesn't work, what I have to do to make it work.
My requirement is to run this docker image in the AWS fargate.
